# Logic: Determining Truth Value

Tags: logic

> Determine the truth value for each of the following statements, and be
> sure to explain your answer with words!
>
> $$(a)~\forall x \in \mathbb Z~(\exists y\in\mathbb Z~(2x + y = 3))$$

I would like help with this, would it be logical to say this is True for any value of $x$ there will always be some $y$ that makes the statement true? I have the same type of logic for part (b).

[image: Question pic]

Comment: Can you show your attempts for to solve this problem?

Comment: Hello! I am not quite sure on if this would be a solution, but:   For all x that belongs to the set of all integers (there exists some y belonging to the set of integers (such that 2x + y =3))
So for any value of x, some y exists so that 2x + y = 3. Which would make this true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me first remind you that the order of the quantifiers matters! The first formula is not equivalent to the second formula!!

**1a)**  Lets translate into english ∀∈ℤ (∃∈ℤ (2+=3))

For every integer x, there exists an integer y such that 2x+y=3.

To examine this, you can try plugging in any value for x in 2+=3, and then seeing if you can find a y.
(example: if x=6, then theres a y= -9, if x=1, y=1, if x=-20, y=43)

This answer is true, regardless of the value of 2x, we can always generate a corresponding integer y that can be added to make the sum equal to 3.

**1b)**  Lets translate this one.

There exists an integer y, such that *every* integer x will make 2x+y=3

So there is exists an x that makes this formula true for every y.

All of these equations would have to be true for some integer x:
2x+(-2)=3
2x+(-1)=3
2x+0=3
2x+1=3
2x+2=3
2x+3=3
...
2x+10000 =3
... and so on, plugging in every integer for y.

Clearly there doesn't exist such a number x that would satisfy every single one of those equations.  So this one would be false.

**2)**  Lets translate this one:
For every member of S that is P, there exists a member of S that is P.

The sentence sounds silly and redundant, but think about what it really means.  For every (thing) there exists a (thing). Obviously true!

In the case that there are multiple members of S that are P, there will exist some members of S that have P.  In the case where there are no members of S that are P, the statement will still be true because there will be no members of S in P.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

(1)
Hint: Can you find examples which rule out each formula?

(2)

We use the fact that $ p \Rightarrow q \equiv \neg q \vee p$. So, we have

$(\forall x) P(x) \Rightarrow (\exists x) P(x)$

$\equiv (\neg \exists x) \neg P(x) \vee (\forall x) P(x)$

$\equiv (\forall x) \neg P(x) \vee (\forall x) P(x)$

$\equiv (\forall x) (\neg P(x) \vee P(x))$

$\equiv (\forall x) (T)$

Q.E.D.